# Converting Javascript Fetch to Google Apps Script URL Fetch

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, urlfetch

Have the JavaScript code from a successful API call but when I try to change it to use Google Apps Scripts URL Fetch function I get an error.
Here's the JavaScript from successful Postman Call

...

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("X-Auth-Token", "Token");
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
myHeaders.append("Cookie", "laravel_session=eyJpdiI6InpSaXcxVk1KQzd4cGMrT1BkWGlOQkQ0Tmt5TjhDRWRLVnlXQVwvYlJlV1EwPSIsInZhbHVlIjoiZGUyc21wWlZERHVJYkVhYks3MCswWXFOZllOQU5kSHdWeDJMbkdSZk5rNFV0N1BuUEI3N1FQT3RpbkhEU3JFRU56Wml4eE9NMmlKVGRqXC9OQ1pwNEJ3PT0iLCJtYWMiOiJjM2Q1NjBkYTAyMGFmNDY3NWJiY2VkMzZjODg0ZDViMDBlM2NmZDVkODBlMzk1YTc0ZTFlOGU4MTM3ODUxYjkxIn0%3D");

var raw = JSON.stringify({"description":"Test Description","invitees":"test@test.com","priority":"10","remind":{"popup":"0","mail":"1","hour":"09:00:00","date":"2020-12-22"},"sync_calendar":true,"task_name":"Test Name"});

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: raw,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("https://private-anon-0eef3aeb66-ricochet.apiary-mock.com/api/v4/leads/lead_id/tasks/", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

...

And here is what I have in Google Apps Script
...

```
     var raw = JSON.stringify({"description":"Test Description",
                            "invitees":"test@test.com",
                            "priority":"10",
                            "remind":{"popup":"0","mail":"1","hour":"09:00:00","date":"2020-12-22"},
                            "sync_calendar":true,
                            "task_name":"Test Name"});
      var headers = { "X-Auth-Token" : "Token"};  
      var params = {
        "method" : "POST",
        'contentType': 'application/json',
        "headers" : headers,
        "payLoad" : raw
      };
      var url = "https://private-anon-0eef3aeb66-ricochet.apiary-mock.com/api/v4/leads/lead_id/tasks/";
      var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,params);
```

...

Here is the error I get when using Google Apps Script

> Exception: Request failed returned code 500. Truncated server response: {"status":false,"message":"Validation failed"}

Comment: In your script, for example, when `Cookie` is included in the request header, what result will you get?

Comment: You are not passing the exact same headers, which you should in order to really compare the two calls. Also, the error you get is from Apps Script of from the API you are calling?